# Populate and only return that populated value

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to just return the populated profile document from the User Document. But I can't seem to code in the logic correctly...What is the way to go about this? I only want to select the profile field to return from the user. I thought of maybe trying `.select("profile).populate({ path: "profile"})`, but that didn't work either.

```
  User.findOne({ _id: req.user._id })
          .populate({ path: "profile"}) <---
          .then(user => {
            res.json(user);
          })
          .catch(() => res.json({ Error: "User Account type is not valid" }));
```

**User Schema**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Create Schema
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  profile: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    refPath: "profile_type"
  },
  profile_type: {
    type: String,
    enum: ["PartnerAdminProfile", "DistrictAdminProfile", "MentorProfile"]
  },

});

module.exports = User = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

**Profile Schema**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Create Schema
const PartnerAdminProfileSchema = new Schema({ <----EDIT redefined schema name
  user: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User"
  },
  profile_picture: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Image",
    date: {
      type: Date,
      default: Date.now
    }
  }
});

module.exports = PartnerAdminProfile = mongoose.model("PartnerAdminProfile", PartnerAdminProfilechema);
```

expected output:

```
profile: {
user: "6546556654564",
profile_picture :{url:https://test.jpg}
}
```

Comment: Could you show sample documents and expected result ?

Comment: @mickl, absolutely

Comment: Can't you just run your `findOne` on `ProfileSchema` passing `req.user._id` as a filtering condition on `user` field ?

Comment: I had to make an edit, I was using an old schema as an example type. Well I have different types of schemas for profiles. So I just want to find a user and populate their profiles. So I wouldn't have to do additional logic to figure out the user's profile type and then search their profile type schema.